# How to fix java virtual machine launcher error

Tags: virtual-machine, java, launcher, runtime-error

Recently i accidentally downloaded and ran jar keylogger. So in fear of it stealing various of my logins i deleted my temp folder, because i had a hunch it had stored some files there for sure. Now every time i start up my computer i get error because i deleted the files which the keylogger used.

heres the picture and text format below 
[image]

```
Error: Unable to acces jarfile
/C:/Users/Maru/AppData/Local/Temp/File2633973980103732350.jar
```

How can i locate or stop the jarfile from running on startup?
I can't find any suspicious looking applications from msconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are on Windows OS. You can stop the .jar file from your task manager. Download Process Hacker from [here](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) and then kill the process. Also download [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download) and the free version of [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/). And then check your system for malware and viruses.

---

If you have backups of you system you could rollback to that backup